# Machine Learning model performs worse on test data than validation data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am quite new to machine learning.

To start things, I wanted to train a model to classify pictures of cats and dogs.

The problem I have is that when I train my model, it gives me a (approximately) 80-85% accuracy on the training data and the validation data. The loss is quite low with about 0.4 - 0.5 on both the validation data and the training data. Because those numbers are quite similar, I suspect that I don't have a problem with overfitting, right?

But when I test my model with pictures from the dataset (which it has not seen before), the accuracy turns out to be around 70%-73%. So it's significantly lower. I was not able to find any information on why this is the case. And, as I said, I suspect that overfitting is not the problem but since I'm a beginner, I'm not quite sure.

My model looks like this (I use tensorflow in python):

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(224,224,3), kernel_initializer="he_uniform"),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer="he_uniform"),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer="he_uniform", kernel_regularizer=l2(.001)),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer="he_uniform", kernel_regularizer=l2(.001)),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(units = 128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.5),
    Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')
])

Trainable params: 3,471,810
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Optimizer, loss:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the dataset, which I use:
https://www.kaggle.com/tongpython/cat-and-dog
I use 3000 images for training (1500 of dogs and 1500 of cats), 1000 for validation and 1000 for testing. There are no duplicates (so no images in the validation set, which are also in the training set and so on).

I preprocess the images like that (and I also use data augmentation):

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input, rescale=1/255, horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, width_shift_range=.2, height_shift_range=.2) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=training_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=64)

valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input, rescale=1/255, horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, width_shift_range=.2, height_shift_range=.2) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=validation_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=64)

test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=64, shuffle=False)
```

EDIT:
Solved the problem. My mistake was that I did not preprocess the train, validation and test data in the exact same way because I misunderstood one parameter. Thank you to all, who helped me.

Comment: If you have iterated repeatedly on your training / test set, you will have inserted bias to your approach in a way that favours the observed fit (but may not necessarily extrapolate well to the new set).

Comment: As C. Cooney said it could be explained by overifitting to the validation set, meaning through trial and error you tried to optimize the validation accuracy while ignoring how well your model generalizes. This can be seen as overfitting, because your model underperforms when put against out of sample data, simulating the problem it was built to solve. Edit: You provided a kaggle link so imagine you are in a competition and you tweak your submission by multiplying with constants just to rank higher in the leaderboard. This does not help when the real test comes.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much so far. So what you suggest is that I try to optimize my model because it is still overfitting? And yes, at the start my model gave a training accuracy of about 80% and a validation accuracy of 60%. That was when I started optimizing my model to close that gap. I dont really get your kaggle example since I only use it to get datasets at the moment, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem results from the fact that for the validation data and the training data you have

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input, rescale=1/255, .....
```

The vgg16.preprocess_input function rescales the pixel value between +1 and -1 so there is no need to include rescale=1/255. In your test generator you do not rescale the pixel values. So remove the rescale=1/255 in the train and validation generators

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My model is training at the moment with the changes applied, which you suggested. However, if I remove the "rescale=1/255" argument from the train and validation generator, the accuracy does not seem to get above 0.5 while training (at the moment epoch 30/100). But when I train the model with rescaling in the train, validation and test generator (I am training 2 models right now), the model seems to behave normal (accuracy 77% at epoch 30/100). I will wait and see what the final result is when predicting the test data. But thank you so far!

Comment: Are your images grayscale? If so you need to set color_mode='grayscale' in flow_from_directory

Comment: No, they are not. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: So my training just finished. The model without the "rescale=1/255" parameter in the train, validation and test data stayed at about 50% accuracy. Not really sure why. But the model where the train, validation and test data were all preprocessed with "rescale=1/255" and the vgg16 preprocess function got a training accuracy of 90%, a validation accuracy of 86% and a test accuracy of also 86%. And thats completely fine for me. Thank you so much.